# Paginating result with mysql limit

Tags: php, mysql

I want to paginate some result using

```
LIMIT no_of_rows, row_offset
```

query in mysql

I runt a script that does this via ajax, the problem is when I fetch the last rows.
How can I fetch the last rows via mysql limit without getting any errors?

Comment: What are the errors that you're getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time you query the table (assuming it does not change every second)
Do it like that:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * 
FROM table_name LIMIT page_size,0;

SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

That way you know how many rows to expect, and you do not give a `LIMIT` which does not exists.

Comment: Thank you. For an ajax call, is it ok to do a request with the query you typed and setup a variable or something with the response I get? Or which is the best approach?

Comment: Ajax or not does not matter. I find it easiest to build the result on the server and return the formatted HTML. PHP does it much faster than JS.

Comment: Yes, I return the formatted HTML via PHP, but I make an ajax request in which I specify how many rows and from whitch offset to fetch.

Comment: yes - it is. b.t.w. if this paged data set is most of the page, maybe no need for AJAX?

Comment: I load only the grid values by ajax